# JavaScript Library to Synchronize Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, synchronization

let's say I'm doing 3 ajax calls and I want to wait for the 3 calls to finish before doing something.

Is there a library out there to synchronize multiple async events in JavaScript ? (using or not jQuery's event system)

Ex.:

```
var sync = new syncLib();
$('a1').click(sync.newListener());
$('a2').click(sync.newListener());

sync.wait(function(e1, e2) {
  // fired when both a1 and a2 are clicked or when 10 seconds have passed
  // e1 and e2 would have properties to know whether or not they timed out or not..
}, 10 /* timeout */));
```

I have found this one: https://github.com/Ovea/js-sync/blob/master/README.md, but timeouts are not supported. (Let's say the second ajax call takes too long, I don't want my synchronization to be hung up, I want to set a 10 secs timeout)

I know I can code something myself, but I'm just checking here (after googling for it)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Since then I found async: https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$.when($.ajax("/"), $.ajax("/"), $.ajax("/")).then(function () {
    alert("all 3 requests complete");
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Answer (score 3):

you can use jquery [**deferred object**](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

here is a useful post http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Comment: +1 and very complete but I will accept Esailija's answer just because he was first to answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `.deferred`, `.when`, `.then` solution mentioned in other answers is much more elegant, but it's also possible write your own simple solution just so you see how this can be done manually.  You just set a counter for how many ajax calls you have in flight and in the success handler for each ajax calls, you decrement the counter and fire your action when the counter gets to zero.

```
function DoMyAjaxCalls(callbackWhenDone) {
    var numAjaxCalls = 3;

    // set timeout so we don't wait more than 10 seconds to fire the callback
    // even if ajax calls aren't done yet
    var timer = setTimeout(callbackWhenDone, 10*1000);

    function checkAjaxDone() {
        --numAjaxCalls;
        if (numAjaxCalls == 0) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callbackWhenDone();
        }
    }

    // first ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test1.html',
        success: function(data) {
            // write code to handle the success function
            checkAjaxDone();
        },
        error: checkAjaxDone
    });

    // second ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test2.html',
        success: function(data) {
            // write code to handle the success function
            checkAjaxDone();
        },
        error: checkAjaxDone
    });

    // third ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test3.html',
        success: function(data) {
            // write code to handle the success function
            checkAjaxDone();
        },
        error: checkAjaxDone
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [library][1] based on `jQuery` made for that purpose.

In simple use-cases, `$.when()` is BEST but `jcon-q-rency` allows you to synchronize any asynchronous code sections.

http://www.megiddo.ch/jcon-q-rency